# Syntax for MySQL query using alias for column

Tags: mysql, alias

I write a query like this in mysql but it not working

```
select name as [your name] from tUsers
```

if I use one word in alias it works correctly like this

```
select name as [name] from tUsers
```

Comment: in `MySQL`, you should use backticks instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is for MSSQL. MySQL has a different syntax

```
select name as `your name` 
from tUsers
```

Use backticks [like the docu suggests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html).

<sub>BTW using `[]` does not work for me in **any** case.</sub>